# I'm looking for the sql term to remove duplicate rows from a report

Tags: sql

The adhoc report tool is a Shazam product and I have a sql filter that has these value options:

```
Is Equal To
Is Between
Is Greater Than
Is Greater or Equal 
Is Less Than 
Is Less or Equal To 
Is Like
Is Not Equal To 
Is Not Between 
Is Not Like
```

The report runs, but I have a couple duplicates of the same Incident Number.  How can I tell it to remove any duplicates?

Comment: Depending on the SQL version, `DISTINCT` may be an option.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the [`DISTINCT`](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-distinct-sql-tutorial/) clause:

> The SQL DISTINCT command used along with the SELECT keyword retrieves only unique data entries depending on the column list you have specified after it.

Comment: @user550500 - You are very welcome. Though in the future, you should tag your SQL questions with the database and database version you are using.

Comment: @user550500 - It makes things easier for people trying to answer your question... Not all SQL databases were made the same or follow the standards in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use the keyword:

```
DISTINCT
```

Update #1

Use it this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Col1, Col2, Col3, ...] 
FROM TableName
```

Comment: I am forced to select one of the filters.  Can I go into the sql statement and enter DISTINCT without using the filter?

Comment: I think the filters are used for the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the keyword DISTINCT after SELECT (eg SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2. . .) it will remove all rows that are *exact* duplicates.  But if the rows are only very similar (for instance, if there's a small spelling difference in on of the fields in the result set) they will not be recognized as duplicates.